# Getting the count of rows from a web table -SELENID

Tags: java, selenide

I am working with Selenide, however, I need to count the number of rows in the table to write tests. The table has the functionality of displaying the number of rows, I want to check that when selecting, for example, 15 rows, 15 is displayed in the table. However, I do not understand exactly how to count them using selenide.

```
<table class="table_pay">
    <tbody>
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
        <div class="srringtable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of rows in the table using Selenide by finding all elements with the class "srringtable" and then using the .size() method.

```
int rowCount = $$(".srringtable").size();
```

Answer (score 0):

`JQuery` will be easy.

```js
let rowCount = $(".srringtable").length;
$("input#count").val(rowCount);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js"></script>

<table class="table_pay">
    <tbody>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
        <div class="srringtable"></div>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="count">
```